How to obtain a URL with # value in Next14 Client Component?
I am using Next14 and have a client component.
I have a URL with a hashvalue
Ex : "www.xyz.com/something/another-thing#abc"
I used usePathname to obtain the URL and am getting "/something/another-thing" as the output and not "something/another-thing#abc".
What should I do?

Try location.hash


import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

function MyComponent() {
    const { asPath } = useRouter();
    const [hash, setHash] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        // This will capture the hash value from the URL when the component mounts
        setHash(window.location.hash);
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Path: {asPath}</h1>
            <h2>Hash: {hash}</h2>
        </div>
    );
}

export default MyComponent;



